# Is there any way to reload a modprobe module once every certain period of time?

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

Link USB wireless adapter which disconnects every 30 minutes, and the only way to make it work again is by reloading its module `ath9k_htc` by running command `rmmod ath9k_htc` and then `modprobe ath9k_htc`

Is there any way to make the module reload itself every half hour?!!!

Comment: Instead of a re start every 30 mins maybe ask why it is doing this disconnect.

Comment: I've already done that I looked up the whole internet seeking for a fix but this is the only way out sadly :(

Comment: But you did not ask us about that? :-) Why not make a new topic about trying to find a fix for the disconnecting. There is likely an error notice somewhere. Just got to track that down and someone will know something about it. We have some brilliant wireless gurus here on AU.

Answer (score 3):

Create a cron job to check the connectivity every 1 min.

```
sudo vi /etc/crontab
```

then add the following line

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/ping -c2 8.8.8.8 || /usr/sbin/modprobe -r ath9k_htc && sleep 0.5 && /usr/sbin/modprobe ath9k_htc
```

Comment: Thanks for fast replaying but please can you tell me what 0.5 stand for ?!!

Comment: 0.5 means half a second.

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless may be dropping because of power management; that is, the feature where the card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Your wireless may be dropping because the channel to which it was connected has suddenly changed.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

Your wireless may be dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: You've been around long enough to know that constantly posting the exact same answer raises a few questions and autoflags the moderators for "duplicate post" concerns.  Is there a reason you're posting this answer to multiple different posts, instead of simply suggesting duplicate closes or such?  Also, OP is asking a different question to what you're answering.

Comment: OP has an X-Y problem. He wants to reload the driver module to get the wireless to reconnect. As was pointed out above, the question should be, how can we stop the dropping in the first place. In many cases, it is solvable by tweaks in the router. Going forward, I will suggest duplicates. Thanks. @ThomasWard